# MVC .Net Redirect to remote unhosted html file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

I am trying to redirect to an unhosted html file in an MVC action. The page returns with corrupted content error. I am trying to redirect like this:

```
return Redirect("file:///C:/test/mytestfile.html");
```

This of course works fine if the file is on a web server:

```
return Redirect("http://myserver/mytestfile.html");
```

Is it even possible to use the file protocol when redirecting in MVC? I've also tried:

```
return new RedirectResult("file:///C:/test/mytestfile.html");
```

and

```
Response.Redirect("file:///C:/test/mytestfile.html");
```

The project I'm doing this in is a bridge solution to overcome some shortcomings in a vendor solution, so unfortunately I can't just move the target files to web server. I really need to redirect to the file on the share where it lives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported and is not a limitation of ASP.NET MVC, it is how web browsers work. You cannot redirect to the `file:///` protocol if the web application is hosted on a web server (`http://`). You can only redirect to `file:///` if the page that is redirecting is also hosted on `file:///`.

More info on the subject can be found [`here`](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18685/are-there-any-know-browsers-that-support-file-url-redirection) and the rules are defined [`here`](https://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#URL_scheme_access_rules).

Comment: Well, now I know. Is this an MVC ASP.Net specific limitation or a more global standard? I was searching for information to find out if what I was trying was even possible, but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. It is how web browsers work.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly have the website do a file read on the HTML file and then output the file to the page. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149969/read-in-a-html-page-within-asp-net-mvc) might be a start. You would end up with a wrapper "page" on your site that mirrored the remote HTML file.